# Headless execution using HlmlUnit Driver Config

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to execute simple testplan in JMeter as

```
TestPlan
-jp@gc - HtmlUnit Driver Config
Thread Group
 -jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler
 -View Results Tree
```

When there is default jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler (url is http://jmeter-plugins.org) the execution is fine but when I alter the url it is giving following issue

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://rcsp.infoaxon.com/reliance-sign-theme/js/jquery-2.1.4.js#3451)
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'IAPC83', ip: '169.254.146.29', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:554)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:530)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$1$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:2)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:446)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:403)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:86)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:490)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/bugs/1615/) in the HtmlUnit driver, you can try updating to newer version of [HtmlUnit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/files/htmlunit/) (2.30 as of now while JMeter is being shipped with HtmlUnit 2.18 which is 3 years old). You can download the newest version of HtmlUnit and replace the following files in "lib" folder of your JMeter installation:

- htmlunit-2.18.jar
- htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar

with their newer versions.

If it resolves your issue you can use new HtmlUnit with the WebDriver Sampler or just use HtmlUnit driver API directly from the [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)